# How can I state an axiom without enumeration?

Tags: amsmath

I am using the ams math package. When this code is executed it states "Axiom of Completeness" with a 1. How do I get rid of the 1?

```
\newtheorem{axiom}{Axiom of Completeness}
\begin{axiom}
Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound. 
\end{axiom}
```

Comment: Hi, for my humble opinion the tag it is wrong. Peraphs was it amsthm?

Comment: Welcome to the site! Great question. The [amsthm manual](https://mirrors.concertpass.com/tex-archive/macros/latex/required/amscls/doc/amsthdoc.pdf#subsection.4.1) should have all the details if you have more questions.

Comment: Can I ask an courtesy to switch the green check mark to @egreg, please? egreg's answer is more complete than mine and also a humble user as me cannot surpass the master :-)

Comment: Isn't the name of the package "[amsmath](https://www.ams.org/arc/tex/amsmath/amsldoc.pdf)" (one word) or "[AMS-LaTeX](http://www.ams.org/arc/resources/amslatex-about.html)"? Otherwise, it should be "[AMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_Mathematical_Society) math" - *"The American Mathematical Society (AMS) is an association of professional mathematicians"*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like this?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem*{axiom*}{Axiom of Completeness}
\theoremstyle{plain}
\begin{document}
\section{Bla}
\begin{axiom*}
Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound. 
\end{axiom*}
\begin{axiom*}
Every nonempty set of real numbers that is bounded above has a least upper bound. 
\end{axiom*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

If you have a single statement called “Axiom of Completeness”, then you can do away with Sebastiano's fine answer.

However, it could be a mess if you're doing set theory and have to state several axioms: defining more and more theorem types would be very hard labor and difficult to maintain.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem*{genericaxiom}{Axiom of \AxiomName} % unnumbered generic axiom
\newcommand{\AxiomName}{\ERROR} % initialize
\newenvironment{axiom}[1]
 {\renewcommand{\AxiomName}{#1}\begin{genericaxiom}}
 {\end{genericaxiom}}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}{Completeness}
This is the axiom of completeness
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}{Choice}
This is the axiom of choice.
\end{axiom}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much to have cited me :-))))...There is a wrong tag in the question. It is not amsmath.